# How to convert string to time.Time

Tags: api, go, controller, beego

When I try to convert this json to time I gets the error

output:

> HERE------------------------------------ 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

raw:

```
{
  "tenantID": "9e266e1a750e45f8862e83341a5d0970",
  "startTime": "2019-4-1T11:45:26.371Z",
  "endTime": "2019-4-10T11:45:26.371Z"
}
```

Controller:

```
var bodyBytes []byte
raw := make(map[string]interface{})
jsons := make(map[string]interface{})

if h.Ctx.Request.Body != nil {
    bodyBytes, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(h.Ctx.Request.Body)
}

json.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &raw)

time1, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339,raw["startTime"].(string));
time2, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339,raw["endTime"].(string));
fmt.Println("HERE------------------------------------",time1,time2)

usageSingle, err := compute.UsageSingleTenant(raw["tenantID"].(string), time1, time2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339), which requires time of the form:

```
2019-04-01T11:45:26.371Z
```

not

```
2019-4-1T11:45:26.371Z
```

When I put the zero padding in your code, it worked fine.  Or if I didn't specify RFC time and instead used:

```
time1, err := time.Parse("2006-2-1T15:04:05.999Z",raw["startTime"].(string));
```